# Reference member variables causing unexpected results

Tags: c++, reference, initialization

I am working on an implementation of a Moog VCF filter that creates a fourth order filter by placing four first order filters in series.  These first order filters all share the same values for their coefficients.  One way of approaching this was to use aggregation and create a filter class whose member variables were reference types:

```
class FirstOrderFilter {
public:
    FirstOrderFilter(float& a1, float& b0, float& b1, float& g) : a1(a1), b0(b0), b1(b1), g(g) {}
    float process(float in);
private:
    // Coefficients
    float& a1;
    float& b0;
    float& b1;
    float& g;

    // x[n-1]
    float previousInput;

    // y[n-1]
    float previousOutput;
};
```

The idea was that I could create an array or vector of filters at the start of the program and any change to the coefficients would cause the member variables for each class to be updated without the need to call a setter function.

This does work but I ran into a few issues. The only two options for initialising the containers that work are:

```
std::vector<FirstOrderFilter> filters (4, FirstOrderFilter{gA1, gB0, gB1, gCutoff});

std::array<FirstOrderFilter, 4> = {
    FirstOrderFilter{gA1, gB0, gB1, gCutoff},
    FirstOrderFilter{gA1, gB0, gB1, gCutoff},
    FirstOrderFilter{gA1, gB0, gB1, gCutoff},
    FirstOrderFilter{gA1, gB0, gB1, gCutoff}
};
```

If I do the following:

```
std::vector<FirstOrderFilter> filters;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    filters.push_back({gA1, gB0, gB1, gCutoff});
```

The program crashes because the output becomes incredibly large (although there is no runtime error produced).  If I use `emplace_back` the program still runs but the filter does not display the correct behaviour.

I looked into using `std::reference_wrapper` but I am not sure of the correct way to use it.  For example, the following does not improve matters:

```
// Coefficients
std::reference_wrapper<float> a1;
std::reference_wrapper<float> b0;
std::reference_wrapper<float> b1;
std::reference_wrapper<float> g;
```

I understand this is caused by the fact that references cannot be copied or assigned, however, I thought `emplace_back` might help get round this.  If I was to use an array instead of a vector, is there another way of initialising the array instead of the cumbersome method above?

Can anyone explain what is happening here?

**Here is a minimal reproducible example:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

float gA1 = 0.0f, gB0 = 0.0f, gB1 = 0.0f;
float gCutoff = 0.0f;

void calculate_coefficients()
{
    gA1 = 1.0f; gB0 = 1.0f / 1.3f; gB1 = 0.3f / 1.3f;
    gCutoff = 1.0f;
}

class Filter {
public:
    Filter(float& a1, float& b0, float& b1, float& g) : a1(a1), b0(b0), b1(b1), g(g) {}
    float process(float in);
private:
    // Coefficients
    float& a1;
    float& b0;
    float& b1;
    float& g;

    // x[n-1]
    float previousInput = 0.0f;

    // y[n-1]
    float previousOutput = 0.0f;
};

float Filter::process(float in)
{
    float out = ((b0*in + b1*previousInput - a1*previousOutput) * g) + a1*previousOutput;
    previousInput = in;
    previousOutput = out;
    return out;
}

std::vector<Filter> filters;

// This produces the expected result
// std::vector<Filter> filters (4, Filter(gA1, gB0, gB1, gCutoff));

int main() {
    // Comment out this loop if using fill constructor 
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
       filters.push_back(Filter(gA1, gB0, gB1, gCutoff));

    calculate_coefficients();

    float out = 1.0f;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < filters.size(); i++)
        out = filters[i].process(out);

    std::cout << std::to_string(out) << std::endl;
}
```

The output produced by running the above code is a negative long double.  Something like -66466164548257686390571008.000000, for example.

Update: This error was caused by declaring the reference types on the same line and not initialising previousInput and previousOutput correctly.

Comment: Not sure why your code "breaks". Nothing in the code you've shown causes that so it's impossible to tell you without a proper [mcve]. With that said, why not use `static` members of the class for the coefficients. Static class members are shared between all instances of the class and would remove any initialization issues with using references.

Comment: I have edited the post to include a proper minimal reproducible example.  The code doesn't "break" as such, it just produces unexpected results.  I am aware of `static` members and other potential ways of doing this.  The point is that the code works perfectly if I create the vector using a fill constructor but if I use `push_back` instead it behaves in a completely different manner.  It was this subtle change that I wanted to ask about.

Comment: What compiler and version are you using? Can't reproduce [here](https://godbolt.org/z/boYqMG), but I'm not sure what the expected output is.

Comment: Apologies, I introduced an error by declaring the reference types on the same line like so `float& a1, b0, b1, g;`  The code now produces the same output (0.350128) regardless of how I create the vectors. I also realised that the long double was a side effect of not initialising the `previousInput` and `previousOutput` variables correctly.  This seems to matter when using g++ but not with the gcc compiler that you used on compiler explorer.  I think I will just go with using `static` members for now.